# Print first and last line of all files in folder

Tags: shell, awk

I have a bunch of log files that get overwritten (`file.log.1`, `file.log.2` etc). When I copy them from the device making them onto my local machine I lose the original time stamps. So I'd like to put them in chronological order. The problem is that I don't necessarily know which is the newest and which is the oldest.

What I'd like to be able to do is, if all the logs are in a directory, print something like this:

```
file: file.log.1
first line: [first line that isn't whitespace]
last line: [last line that isn't whitespace]
```

I can just write a python script to do this, but I'd much rather do it with linux built-ins if possible. Is this a job for awk/sed? Or would this really be better off for a scripting language? If yes to awk/sed, how woul dyou go about doing it?

I found this awk command by searching, but it only accepts one file name and will print whatever the last line is (and there can be a variable number of empty lines at the end)

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print }END{ print }' filename
```

Comment: What are you using to copy the files? If you are copying to another linux file system then you should be able to preserve user, timestamp data. e.g. `cp -p`

Comment: It's a windows CE system that I'm copying from to my linux host

Comment: Even when copying from a FAT filesystem, `cp -a` or `cp -p` should preserve the timestamp.

Comment: Looks like classic example of [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I like `sed` the answer can be

```
for file in file.log.*
do
   echo "file: $file"
   echo -n "first line: "
   cat "$file" | sed -n '/^\s*$/!{p;q}'
   echo -n "last line: "
   tac "$file" | sed -n '/^\s*$/!{p;q}'
done
```

Comment: No need to `echo+cat` and `echo+tac`, you could just `sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*$/!{s/^/first line: /p;q}' "$file"` and `sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*$/!h;$!d;g;s/^/last line: /p' "$file"`

Comment: @don_crissti Nice. I like such decisions. But `echo+tac` much simple and, in case of big file, quicker.

Comment: It works like a charm. But I really don't know what the thing is you put into the sed argument, especially the {p; g} part. Could you give any resouce on this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

an awk command:

```
awk -v OFS=: '
    FNR==1 {
        # the last non-blank line from the previous file
        if (line) {print filename, fnr, line}
        filename=FILENAME
        line=""
        p=0
    } 
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {next} 
    !p {
        # the first non-blank line
        print FILENAME, FNR, $0; p=1
    }
    {fnr=FNR; line=$0} 
    END {print filename, fnr, line}
' *
```

for each file, print the filename, line number and line, colon-separated.

GNU awk v4 has BEGINFILE and ENDFILE patterns which simplify things quite a bit:

```
gawk -v OFS=: '
    BEGINFILE {p=0} 
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {next} 
    !p {print FILENAME, FNR, $0; p=1}
    {fnr=FNR; line=$0} 
    ENDFILE {print FILENAME, fnr, line}
' *
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk -F'\n' -vRS="" '
  {
    print "file: " FILENAME;
    gsub(/\n[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+\n/,"");
    print "first line: " $1;
    print "last line: " $NF;
  }
' file.log.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use `head` and `tail`:

**EDIT** (Thank you for the suggestion @don_crissti!)

```
for file in file.log.*
do
   echo "file: $file"
   echo -n "first line: "
   grep -v '^\s*$' "$file" | head -n1
   echo -n "last line: "
   grep -v '^\s*$' "$file" | tail -n1
done
```

Comment: As per the question, OP wants to print the "first & last lines that aren't whitespace". So you could do something like `grep -v '^\s*$' "$file" | head -n 1` and `grep -v '^\s*$' "$file" | tail -n 1` to get the expected result.

Comment: As a variant you can strip `head` command if use option `-m1` for `grep`

Answer (score 2):

What? No Perl?

```
for file in file.log.*; do 
    echo "FILE: $file"; 
    perl -ne 'if(/\S/){$k++; $l=$_}; 
              print "First line: $_" if $k==1; 
              END{print "Last line: $l\n"}' "$file";  
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in file.log.*` : iterate over all files whose names starts with `file.log.` in the current directory and save each of them as `$file`.
- `echo "FILE: $file";` : print the file name.
- `perl -ne` : read the current input file line by line (`-n`), saving each line as the special Perl variable `$_`, and run the script given by `-e` on it.
- `if(/\S/){$k++; $l=$_}` : if the current line matches a non-whitespace character (`\S`), save the line as `$l` and increment the counter `$k` by one.
- `print "First line: $_" if $k==1;` : print the current line (`$_`) if `$k` is `1`. This will print the 1st non-whitespace line.
- `END{print "Last line: $l\n"}` : this is executed after all input lines have been read. Since we save each non-whitespace line as `$l`, at the end of the file, `$l` will be the last non-whitespace line. Therefore, this will print the last line.

---

Another approach:

```
for file in file.log.*; do 
    printf "FILE: %s\nFirst line: %s\nLast line: %s\n\n" \
        "$file" \
        "$(grep -Em 1 '\S' "$file")" \
        "$(tac "$file" | grep -Em1 '\S' )"; 
done
```

#### Explanation

This is the same `for` loop only here we're using `printf` to print three strings. The file name, and the output of these two commands:

- `grep -Pm 1 '\S' "$file"` : The `-E` activates Extended Regular Expressions which let us use `\S` for "non-whitespace". The `-m1` means "exit after the first match found".
- `tac "$file" | grep -Em1 '\S'` : `tac` is the inverse of `cat`. It will print the contents of a file, but from the last line to the first line. Therefore, this command will print the last non-whitespace line.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a sed answer that only reads through each file once (hopefully faster than multiple `sed`, `cat` and `tac` invocations, if the files are large):

```
for file in file.log.*; do
    echo "file: $file"
    sed -n "
/[^[:space:]]/ {                # Match first non-whitespace line
    h                           # Copy to hold buffer
    s/^/first line: / p         # Add prefix and print
:loop
    $ {                         # Match last line
        g                       # Get contents of hold buffer
        s/^/last line: / p      # Add prefix and print
    }
    n                           # Load next line
    /[^[:space:]]/ h            # Copy non-whitespace line to hold buffer
    b loop                      # Jump back to process next line
}" "$file"
done
```

Comment: I think you could use a one-liner... actually a two-liner as there's a new line after the backslash: `for file in file.log.*; do sed -n '/[^[:space:]]/ {h;s/^/file: '"$file"'\ ` _enter a new line here_ `first line: /p;:loop;${g;s/^/last line: /p};n;/[^[:space:]]/h; b loop}' "$file"; done`

Comment: @don_crissti sure - pretty much replace newlines with `;`.  I find the indented, commented version easier to read though :)

Comment: I know that. I meant without the `"echo file: $file"` part, if you read the code in my comment. Also, don't forget to quote the last `$file` otherwise your solution will fail for file names with spaces and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
strm_1st_last() ( unset l i c n
l=1 i='i\\\\' c='c\\\\' n='\
';  eval "echo |sed -n \":b
    /[^[:blank:]]/h;$( wc -l "$@" | 
    sed -e '${1!d' -e "};s/[\"\/]/\\\\&/g
    s/^[ 0]*\([^ 0-9]\)/1$i$n empty: \1/;/\n/b
    s|^ *\([0-9]\{1,\}\) *\(.*\)|\\
    \$((1+(l+=\\1)-\\1)){$i$n\\2$n :l\\
         s/.*[^[:blank:]]/    \\&/p;//h;t\\
         n;\$((l-1)){ //bb$n//!$c$n\ALL BLANK$n};bl$n}\\
    \${l}{ x;s/^/    /p;s/.*//;x;d$n}|")"'" - "$@"'
)
```

That is a function which relies on one `sed` process to build a workable script for a second. Well, it does not *just* rely on a sub-shelled `sed`, but also `wc` to first get the total line numbers for each of its arguments, and the shell itself to tally usably the arithmetic expressions `sed` builds as line references for the second `sed`.

Basically it handles all arguments as a single stream. For example, if you do:

```
seq 10 > file1; seq 5 > file2; sed -n \$= file[12]
```

`sed` will print...

```
15
```

...because it automatically concatenates all filename arguments into a single data stream. So we just work with that.

First `wc` is asked for a report on all of their lengths, and then `sed` goes to work moulding that into a workable input script for a second `sed`.

If `wc` reports any of the files to have 0 lines `sed` will print *empty :filename* for it and all others before anything else. *(probably just 0 lines would be more accurate, though).*

If, while scanning a section of input lines that comprises an entire file `sed` encounters no non-blank characters at all, `sed` will report it *ALL BLANK* *(which is the only type of line report that is not indented)*

For all other cases, `sed` prints the first and last non-blank lines for each of its arguments and precedes each indented pair with the non-indented filename. This does not handle filenames containing newlines - though it probably wouldn't require much more to do it.

So if I do...

```
strm_1st_last file[12]

file1
    1
    10
file2
    1
    5
```

or...

```
: >file2; strm_1st_last file[12]

empty: file2
file1
    1
    10
```

...or...

```
strm_1st_last ~/*.sh


empty: /home/mikeserv/alleq.sh
empty: /home/mikeserv/mansed5.sh
/home/mikeserv/chrome.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    ) &
/home/mikeserv/crap.sh
ALL BLANK

/home/mikeserv/getopts.sh
    c=$# t=\     l='
    done; printf '%s\n' "'${str#?}'"; done
/home/mikeserv/mansedmaybe.sh
    mansed () {
    );}
/home/mikeserv/mansed.sh
    mansed () {
    );}
/home/mikeserv/pr_after.sh
    pr_after() if       _i= _o=D OPTIND=1 _n='\
        fi
/home/mikeserv/script.sh
    #!/usr/bin/sh
    echo done
/home/mikeserv/serial.sh
    sq() ( IFS=\' set -f
    #   a               b
/home/mikeserv/your_config.sh
    zifs() { eval "shift ${3+3}
    )
/home/mikeserv/ytplay.sh
    ytplay() ( 
    )
/home/mikeserv/zifs.sh
    zifs() { eval "shift ${3+3}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same need. I did it like this:

`for f in */*.log; do echo $f; head -1 $f; tail -1 $f; done`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for file in $(ls) ; do cat $file | sed -n '1p;$p' ; done
```

Answer (score -2):

Using find you could try:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -n '1p;$p' {} \; -print
```

Comment: Did you notice that the question says that the file(s) can contain lines that are entirely whitespace, and the OP wants the first and last lines that have non-blank content?  No, I guess you didn’t.